# ng-bind or ng-bind-template is not showing the initial text

Tags: angularjs

HTML

```
<span ng-bind-template="{{scopeProperty1}} {{scopeProperty2}}">loading...</span>
```

JS

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $scope.$apply(function(){
     $scope.scopeProperty1 = "Mr."
     $scope.scopeProperty2 = "Mark Rajcok"
   })
}, 1000);
```

i tried this, the initial 'loading...' text is not coming up on the screen. I used a timeout to set the scopeProperty1, scopeProperty2. The properties are displayed after timeout, till then an empty space is shown instead of 'loading...' text

Comment: Why are you using `setTimeout` and not `$timeout`?

Answer (score 4):

The `ng-bind-tremplate` attribute [overrides the internal `text`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L114) on the first `$digest` loop.

There are several ways of working around it, `ng-cloak`, clever use of `or` operator in the `template` text, adding a flag and using `ng-show`/`ng-hide` based on it, etc.

#### Using the ternary operator

An example using the poor man's ternary operator:

```
<span ng-bind-template="{{scopeProperty1}} {{scopeProperty2}} {{(!scopeProperty1 && !scopeProperty2) && 'Loading ...' || ''}}"></span>
```

Here is a working example with the same principle: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wa38wwxuuE2WWYeEtCOA?p=preview

#### ng-cloak

Solution with `ng-cloak` will require another `html` element:

```
<span ng-bind-template="{{scopeProperty1}} {{scopeProperty2}}">
    <span ng-cloak>Loading ...</span>
</span>
```

However, this will cause problems if you are using `ng-bind-template` at a place which does not allow other elements inside it (like `option` tag). In that case, you'll need some clever CSS or a computed property to do this task. See the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak) for IE work arounds.

Comment: could you give me an example of one ways to do it. I used ng-cloak attribute like `<span ng-bind-html="scopeProperty1" ng-cloak>loading...</span> `, but still im not seeing 'loading...' text on page load

Comment: Yes this is the expected result. But it will become complicated if the  'Loading ...' text is big

Comment: Added the solution using `ng-cloak` but that sort of defeats the purpose of using `ng-bind-template`.